# How to parse password in varbinary from database to IdentityUser string in Web Api Authentication

Tags: c#, database, parsing, asp.net-web-api, ef-model-builder

I have in my database a column named `Password` of type `Varbinary(150)`.
When I want to consult that database in the web api, for example:

`var dbCon = ApplicationDbContext.Create(connectionStringUsers.ToString());
 var users = dbCon.Users;
 var list = users.ToList();`

In the last line I have this error:

> The 'PasswordHash' property on 'IdentityUser'4' could not be set to a 'System.Byte[]' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'.

It know that if I change my schema from type `Varbinary` to `Varchar` it is going to work. But I cant change the schema. How can I hack this parse?

Thank you

**UPDATE 1**

Maybe something like this:

`modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("MyUsers", "dbo").Property(p => p.PasswordHash).HasColumnType("varbinary");`

But I get this error:

> error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.String[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=Max,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False]' of member 'PasswordHash' in type 'OhmioWEBAPI.Models.ApplicationUser' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.varbinary[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=8000,FixedLength=False]' of member 'Password' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.ApplicationUser'.

Comment: Make `PasswordHash` on the code side a `Byte[]` instead of a string?

Comment: Do you say in my `ApplicationUser` class? I thought to override it somehow, like `override public byte PasswordHash { get; set; }` but I cant due to the type if it is not `string` I cant override it.

Comment: You can't change the signature of it in an override, you would have to change it on the base class.

Comment: Is this is asp.net identity?  Did you do any customizations to it?

Comment: But base class is part of the asp.net identity, so I cant change it. 
Yes I am using asp. identity. This makes me a collumn `PasswordHash: varchar` in my database that I need to be `varbinary` insted of `varchar`